# Is Asking A Question On Proper Temperature & Humidity Measuring On-Topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've got a question that is about how to accurately measure temperature and humidity to prevent invalid data being gathered. However, these measurements are for both outdoor and indoor. Would that fall under this site? I couldn't find any site that touches on those topics, which would also involve the scientific method and proper testing methodology. Earth sciences which involves climate was the best one I could find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accurate measurements of temperature and humidity are essential for both weather and climate science.  It involves physics, engineering, metrology, and practical matters.  Anyone measuring temperature for scientific purposes will need to take all those aspects into account, certainly when applied to Earth Science.

Therefore, I think it should be on-topic.

Comment: I posted my question here https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/8317/accurately-measuring-indoor-outdoor-air-temperature-relative-humidity if overall it does not meet topic, please feel free to delete it. Thank you.